# Ошибка авторизации VK

Tags: python, вконтакте, auth, oauth

Есть скрипт по отправке некоторых сообщений (не спам, не флуд, не реклама), работал с ним уже более полугода, все было отлично.

Сегодня при попытке авторизации выдало следующую ошибку: `vk.exceptions.VkAuthError: OAuth2 authorization error`

Пробовал логиниться через другое приложение - не помогло.

Вот код самой авторизации:

```
import vk
session = vk.AuthSession('idприложения', 'логин', 'пароль', scope='messages,users,friends')
vk_api = vk.API(session)
```

Если убрать из `scope='messages,users,friends'` флаг messages, то ошибка пропадает и авторизация проходит, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена не была, но вот ее причина:

> С 15 февраля 2019 года методы секции messages по умолчанию будут доступны для вызова только с ключом доступа сообщества.
>
> Если Вы планируете начать разработку мессенджера, после 15 февраля 2019 года для этого потребуется получить в Поддержке тестовый доступ, подразумевающий работу методов секции Messages с ключами администраторов Вашего Standalone-приложения.
>
> Для получения полного доступа к пользовательскому Messages API приложению будет необходимо пройти модерацию.

Источник:
https://vk.com/dev/messages_api